# how to get solr termVectorComponent results using solrj

Tags: java, solr, solrj, tf-idf

I am trying to write this query;

```
localhost/solr/tvrh/?q=queryString&version=2.2&indent=on&tv.tf_idf=true
```

using solrj.

I want to get tf and idf values below;

```
<lst name="doc-40797">
<str name="uniqueKey">test20508</str>
<lst name="content">
<lst name="98">
<double name="tf-idf">0.002304147465437788</double>
</lst>
<lst name="apaan">
<double name="tf-idf">0.16666666666666666</double>
</lst>
<lst name="aryadea">
<        double name="tf-idf">1.0</double>
</lst>
<lst name="chelsea">
<double name="tf-idf">0.005208333333333333</double>
</lst>
<lst name="gua">
<double name="tf-idf">0.05555555555555555</double>
</lst>
<lst name="osa">
<double name="tf-idf">0.004662004662004662</double>
</lst>
<lst name="pegangı">
<double name="tf-idf">0.5</double>
</lst>
<lst name="rt">
<double name="tf-idf">1.4009526478005044E-4</double>
</lst>
<lst name="vs">
<double name="tf-idf">0.0030581039755351682</double>
</lst>
</lst>
</lst>
<str name="uniqueKeyFieldName">id</str>
<lst name="doc-40746">
<str name="uniqueKey">test20457</str>
<lst name="content">
<lst name="075">
<double name="tf-idf">0.027777777777777776</double>
</lst>
<lst name="9">
<double name="tf-idf">9.76657876745776E-5</double>
</lst>
<lst name="atlético">
<double name="tf-idf">0.045454545454545456</double>
</lst>
<lst name="co">
<double name="tf-idf">1.1130899376669635E-4</double>
</lst>
<lst name="http">
<double name="tf-idf">1.034233116144379E-4</double>
</lst>
<lst name="jorna">
<double name="tf-idf">0.25</double>
</lst>
<lst name="lh">
<double name="tf-idf">0.07142857142857142</double>
</lst>
<lst name="ngn">
<double name="tf-idf">0.5</double>
</lst>
<lst name="osa">
<double name="tf-idf">0.004662004662004662</double>
</lst>
<lst name="puntuaciones">
<double name="tf-idf">1.0</double>
</lst>
<lst name="t">
<double name="tf-idf">7.038783698176955E-5</double>
</lst>
<lst name="vavelco">
<double name="tf-idf">0.2</double>
</lst>
<lst name="vía">
<double name="tf-idf">0.03125</double>
</lst>
</lst>
</lst>
<str name="uniqueKeyFieldName">id</str>
```

Up to now;

```
        SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery(queryString);
        query.setQueryType("/tvrh");
        query.setParam("tv.tf_idf", true);
        QueryResponse response = server.query(query);
```

I have written the query and I think I am gonna need QueryResponse object, I think it is true. But I don't know what is next to get those tf-idf values using `solrj`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there:

```
QueryResponse qr = server.query(query);
TermsResponse resp = qr.getTermsResponse();
```

The [TermsResponse](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_0_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/TermsResponse.html) object contains the term vector component output. Not sure if it contains all the information though.

Comment: first of all thank you for your answer. I thought nobody was gonna help me. Thank you again. I now can get tf and idf values by using solution of another stackoverflow question(http://goo.gl/FLWx0). But since results turns document by document(as it shown in the question) I can only get one document's tf idf values, how can I get all document's values?